# Next.js equivalent for useRouteMatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm migrating a React app to Next.js.

Since Next.js doesn't use `"react-router-dom"`, I need to change some of the React Router hooks so that they work with Next.js.

One of them is `useRouteMatch`.

I want to get this line of code to work with Next.js -

```
const match = useRouteMatch<{lang?: Language}>('/map/:lang([a-z]{2})?');
```

I haven't managed to find an equivalent method or workaround for this yet.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: There's no built-in equivalent in Next.js. You have to create your own logic to handle the matching based on what's returned by `next/router`'s `pathname`/`asPath` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Everything about nextjs route is in next/route.

You might be looking at router.pathname

```
const Component = () => {
   const router = useRouter() //now u can use the router object
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object

Comment: I'm not sure how I would match ```'/map/:lang([a-z]{2})?'``` with ```router.pathname``` though as ```pathname``` is a property not a method.